# C++ : Vector of template class

Tags: c++, generics, vector

I have a template class named Cell as follows:-

```
template<class T>class Cell
{
    string header, T data;
}
```

Now I want another class Named Row. Row will have a vector named Cells such that I can add both Cell and Cell type elements to that vector. Is it possible?

If so, how can I do that?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want a row to hold, for example, a Cell<int>, a Cell<float> and any other cell type in the one vector<>?

Comment: Yes you are right. I exactly want that.

Comment: is that mean you want polymorphic container? you can only use dynamic polymorphism (inheritance) and not static polymorpism (templates).

Comment: @Elazar, Would you please provide me some sample codes for that?

Comment: *"I have a template class named Cell"* no, you don't. That is a **class template**, which means, it is *not* a class. `Cell<int>` is a class. `Cell<float>` is a class as well, as is `Cell<Cell<std::vector<double>>>`. But they are three different, independent classes that have nothing in common.

Comment: @JakirHossain - Skizz provided exactly what I am talking about.

Comment: All elements of a vector must be of the same type, so you cannot place a `Cell<float>` and a `Cell<int>` together. You need to use pointers and inheritance,  and you must know what you are doing. It is all too easy to create an unusable base class with all the meat in the children, and then you have no ways to access it. You need to put meat in the base class. Which means it must have a usable interface that does not depend on T.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

With the extra detail you've provided, the first two answers won't work. What you require is a type known as a variant for the cell and then you can have a vector of those. For example:-

```
enum CellType
{
  Int,
  Float,
  // etc
};

class Cell
{
  CellType type;
  union
  {
    int i;
    float f;
    // etc
  };
};

class Vector
{
  vector <Cell> cells;
};
```

This, however, is a pain to add new types to as it requires a lot of code to maintain. An alternative could use the cell template with a common base class:-

```
class ICell
{
  // list of cell methods
};

template <class T>
class Cell : public ICell
{
  T data;
  // implementation of cell methods
};

class Vector
{
  vector <ICell *> cells;
};
```

This might work better as you have less code initially to update to add a new cell type but you have to use a pointer type in the cells vector. If you stored the cell by value, `vector <ICell>`, then you will lose data due to [object slicing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing).

Comment: +1.
union is not just pain, it is also not type-safe, which is the whole purpose of templates.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'll use the second method. Thanks all guys trying to help me.

Comment: One more thing, can u please provide sample codes to add elements and accessing elements using iterator? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @JakirHossain: To keep to the principle of single responsibility, ask more questions (inserting into vector, iterating, etc) rather than expand this one.

Comment: Icell can't be used to access the encapsulated data. And you can't define a virtual function in base class to provide access to data since then you would move the 'typename T' up the class hierarchy and you would face the same problem again, that of defining vector<Icell<T>> cells; which is not allowed. Therefore I do not think this is the correct answer

Answer (score 13):

The reason why **this is NOT possible** in C++, but possible in Java/Python is because: in a C++ vector, the STL container's storage (returned by vector::data()) contains all the object instantiations sequentially packed. In which each element must have the same size. This makes addressing fast and convenient. Therefore, suppose you define a template class A,

```
template <class T>
class A{
  int id;
  T obj;
};
```

Its size will depend on the template variable "T obj". Pushing the same class A of a different template type T will make each element in the vector have different sizes, thus, this is impossible. The only way is to use the vector of shared_ptr or unique_ptr of a base class. Both shared_ptr and unique_ptr are supported by C++11 and Boost. Each derived-class element can have different template types. In this way, when the base class pointer's destructor is called, the derived class's destructor will be invoked. For example,

```
#include <memory>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class A{};

template <class T>
class AImpl : public A{
public:
    T obj;
    AImpl(T _obj):obj(_obj){}
    ~AImpl(){
        cout << "Deleting " << obj << endl;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    AImpl <string>* a1 = new AImpl <string> ("string1234");
    AImpl <int>* a2 = new AImpl <int> (1234);
    AImpl <double>* a3 = new AImpl <double> (1.234);
    vector <shared_ptr<A>> As;
    As.push_back(shared_ptr<A>(a1));
    As.push_back(shared_ptr<A>(a2));
    As.push_back(shared_ptr<A>(a3));
}
```

Remember to compile with -std=c++11 to enable C++11.

Output:

```
Deleting string1234
Deleting 1234
Deleting 1.234
```

And you get what you want! :)

In Java/Python, every class-object variable is actually a pointer, thus, a Java Array of A or a Python list of A is equivalent to a C++ array of pointers of A. Thus, you get essentially the same functionality without explicitly creating shared_ptrs.

Comment: Your program is showing the error as `cpp:25:13: error: 'shared_ptr' was not declared in this scope`

Comment: @PraveenVinny That is because you did not compile with -std=c++11. shared_ptr is in <memory> for C++11 only.

Answer (score 6):

The other answer is good, but you probably wanted:

```
template<class T>
class Row
{
private:
    class Cell {
        string header;
        T data;
    }

    std::vector<Cell> cells;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Something like this?

```
template<class T>
class Row
{
private:
   std::vector<Cell<T> > cells;
};
```

Okay, this answer is incorrect.

So, if you want to store in one `vector` different cells - you should use some dynamic type identification (you can use one base-class and store pointer to it in vector, that use only virtual functions, that are overrided in all derived classes, you can store something like `boost::any` and save some `type-identification` for each inserted element, for cast them into real type and work with it).

Comment: Jakir - note the space before the last `>`, to avoid confusion with `>>` operator. C++11 doesn't need this though.

Comment: It might not work. Because when creating Row type object I have to provide the type parameter. And the vector will be of that type.

Comment: @JakirHossain Then you can add one more template parameter. And use that for Row specific things and use T for the cells.

Comment: @JakirHossain You cannot push in one vector different types, without using some baseclass or something else, that allows yoo to know, what type exactly have each element.

Comment: @JakirHossain - I want to elaborate the problem with what you are asing for: `vector` is an array, so it should have the same static type for all the elements in it, but Cell<int> and Cell<char> are non-related types (unlike generic classes in jave).