# accessing objects in a vector of template class objects

Tags: c++, templates

i am having a vector of various objects of a template class by implementing this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36588158/5088457

I'm developing with qt. But I'm having trouble casting/accessing these objects. So my question is, how do i get the objects behind a shared_ptr, when I don't know the templates type? As you can see in the code snippet below, it's about getting an AImpl object out of the vector As. Thanks!

I think the authors code snippet is a good minimal example:

```
class A{};

template <class T>
class AImpl : public A{
public:
    T obj;
    AImpl(T _obj):obj(_obj){}
    ~AImpl(){
        cout << "Deleting " << obj << endl;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    AImpl <string>* a1 = new AImpl <string> ("string1234");
    AImpl <int>* a2 = new AImpl <int> (1234);
    AImpl <double>* a3 = new AImpl <double> (1.234);
    vector <shared_ptr<A>> As;
    As.push_back(shared_ptr<A>(a1));
    As.push_back(shared_ptr<A>(a2));
    As.push_back(shared_ptr<A>(a3));
}
```

Comment: Type erasure is not some magical weapon. Yes, you put all those objects into a vector - but why? What do you actually want to accomplish? C++ is a strongly typed language, so to do anything useful with your objects, you need to somehow remember/figure out the right type again. If you don't have a way to do that, then type erasure probably was not the right solution.

Comment: In other words: You told us that you used a hammer, that the nail is now stuck in the wood and that you'd like to get it back out. There are many ways to get that nail back out. Some of them are slow. Some of them involve destroying the wood. But we can't give you a helpful answer because we don't know why you put the nails in there and what the purpose of getting them out again is. Maybe you didn't actually need a hammer and wood? This looks like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377), so I suggest you describe what you actually want to accomplish in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So my question is, how do I get the objects behind a `shared_ptr`, when I don't know the templates type?

The answer is **you can't**, respectively, you can't **from outside of `Aimpl`**, which is the only place where the type of the stored object is known.

Type erasure is used mostly when all the type-erased objects share some common interface. In your case, for example, you can type the contents of `int`, `std::string`, and `double` into the output stream. To perform this via a *pointer-to-base* `A`, you need to use `virtual` functions:

```
class A
{
  public: virtual void print() const = 0;
};

template <class T>
class AImpl : public A
{
  T obj;
public:      
  AImpl(T _obj) : obj(_obj) { }      
  ~AImpl() { cout << "Deleting " << obj << endl; }

  virtual void print() const override
  {
    cout << obj << endl;
  }
};
```

Then, you can print out the value of all type-erased objects stored in `As` as follows:

```
for (const auto ptr& : As) As->print();
```

Comment: Thanks it works! I'm using these type erased objects because they share a common-interface. My data is some sort of a key-value pair, where the value can be a primitive type or even a complex one.