# C++: Creating a C++ vector of a template struct

Tags: c++, templates, struct, stdvector

I have the following struct:

```
template <typename A, typename B>
struct Name {

};
```

I am trying to create a vector of type Name i.e. something like `std::vector<Name>`.

In the rest of the code, the struct is initialized in such a way that I do not know the type of A and B but I expect they are always the same.

I tried to obtain the types of A and B as follows:

```
#include <cxxabi.h>
int status;
std::string tname = typeid(class_object).name(); // class_object is a Name object
std::cerr << abi::__cxa_demangle(tname.c_str(), NULL, NULL, &status) << std::endl;
```

and obtained `Name<void (*)(), void (*)()>`.

Then I tried to create the vector as `std::vector<Name<void (*)(), void (*)()>> nameVec;` but I am getting `no matching function for call to` error.

I used the following [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16210707/c-vector-of-template-class) but without success probably because I am unsure how the struct in my case was initialized.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can we get a [mre]?

Comment: Please show a complete example -- it's not clear what "the rest of the code" mean.

Comment: The error message continued after "no matching function for call to".

Comment: You can't create a vector of class templates. You need polymorphism and to store base class pointers in the vector. You could possibly use a vector of `std::any` or a vector of a `std::variant<...>` instance.

Comment: @churill Yes, that is precisely what I mean. The problem is I cannot find out in my case the types of ```Type1``` and ```Type2```. The object is created from a macro function that returns ```Name{}``` without explicitly setting ```Type1``` and ```Type2```.

Comment: Can you change the definition of `Name`?

Comment: Note that `Name` is not a type! It only becomes a type when instantiated with template parameters.

Comment: I unfortunately cannot change ```Name```. I can initialize the object as ```const auto name0 = COMPILE_F(f);``` where f is a function and it works correctly but I do not see what ```auto``` is and cannot deduce it from the macro function ```COMPILE_F```.

Comment: Then use `decltype`.

Comment: If it comes from the macro, its type is `decltype(COMPILE_F(f))`.

Comment: (you could have described the problem you're having more clearly in the question, so all these comments wouldn't be necessary)

Comment: Thanks so much! It works.

Answer (score 2):

`Name` is not a type, it is a template. `Name<int, int>` would be a type, distinct from `Name<std::string, std::string>`.

You can create an alias to the type of an object you are given.

```
using class_object_t = decltype(class_object);

std::vector<class_object_t> vec;
vec.push_back(class_object);
```

If you want to find what `A` and `B` are for an instantiation of `Name`, and can't change `Name`, you can create a trait.

```
template <typename>
struct Name_trait;

template <typename A, typename B>
struct Name_trait<Name<A, B>> {
    using first_type = A;
    using second_type = B;
};

template <typename N>
using Name_first_t = typename Name_trait<N>::first_type;

template <typename N>
using Name_second_t = typename Name_trait<N>::second_type;

Name<int, char> n;
static_assert(std::is_same_v<int, Name_first_t<decltype(n)>>);    
static_assert(std::is_same_v<char, Name_second_t<decltype(n)>>);
```